# Storing or assigning a hex value into a int

Tags: c

I am trying to write a simple c program where the intention is as follows.

1. open a file file.txt which has a list of hex numbers.
2. read line by line each number and send each number through a function call.

My target is that i have a testbench where one of the variable is a uint64_t type and need to assign the value to it.

The example file.txt is here:

```
0xf169e3f00
0xf169e3f14
0xf169e3f34
0xf7e3a3f00
```

I tried writing a code in different ways but could not succeed. looking for some suggestion/code review
here is the snippet of sample code i tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int fun(int a){

printf("%d", a);
}
int main()
{
FILE *fptr;
int c,a;
char line[500];
if ((fptr = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
printf("Error! File cannot be opened.");
exit(1)
}
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr)) {
printf("%s", line);
printf("read is %x\n",c);
sscanf(line,"%d\n",&a); 
fun(a);
}
fclose(fptr);
return 0
}
```

my expectation is to read the hex using a integer type..

Comment: Please don't spam tags. Please format your code.

Comment: Also your question and your code shows you're missing some fundamental parts of the basics of C. Please go back to your beginners text-book and learn about what format specification `sscanf` (and its family of functions) support and what they do. Also read the book about passing arguments, and what happens when you pass an argument.

Comment: See also `strtoul`

Answer (score 3):

Since your aim is to read `uint64_t` values, you should declare your variable as such, and not `int`. Also, you must use the correct conversion specifiers for `scanf` and `printf` when printing `uint64_t`s.

That would mean using the `SCNx64` macro in `scanf` and for `printf` you'd have to use `PRIx64`.

Example:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    FILE* fptr = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (!fptr) {
        perror("file.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    uint64_t c;     // correct type
    char line[500];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr)) {
        if(sscanf(line, "%" SCNx64, &c) != 1) {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^
            fprintf(stderr, "could not parse %s as a uint64_t\n", line);
            return 1;
        }
        printf("read is %" PRIx64 "\n", c);
//                      ^^^^^^^^^
        printf("as dec  %" PRIu64 "\n", c); // same number, base 10
//                      ^^^^^^^^^
        
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ted, This was really insightful. incase if i want to assign the output of PRIx64 (c) into another variable of same integer type(uint64_t) do we have provision for that to do so?  ilke i have a another variable defined as unit64_t var, and now i want to assign val == PRIx64(c)

Comment: @vijay You're welcome. That's just a simple assignment then: `uint64_t other_variable = c;` - The `PRIx64` macro expands to a string literal (usually `"ul"` or `"ull"`) and should only be used with `printf`

Comment: But that turns out to be a dec val.  lets say printf("read is %#" PRIx64 "\n", c); is giving me 0xf11202 . when i do uint64_t = c it turns out to be some dec value.

Comment: @vijay Internally, it's stored in binary format.  You can choose how to print it as I showed in the example. `printf("%" PRIx64, other_variable );` would print it in hex format.

Comment: okay, got it. very nice of you and helpful. thanks again Ted